# Deploying Django for free

Tags: django, django-deployment

I created a project with django,and I want to deploy it. I prefer not to spend any money on webserver, host...
Is it possible?
How can I do that?
By the way, I can't use Heroku.

Comment: So look up free web hosting and if that fails, look how to host your own web server?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, but in any case there is no way for us to recommend anything without knowing why you can't use Heroku.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman because of US sanctions on Iran, I can't use heroku. I tried to create an account there, but they said they can't do this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that exist. The free option has some limitations off course, but it works fine for a free option.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/